# Prevent rows with same col1 and different col2

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005, constraints

Is it possible to create a constraint to prevent **different** `Col2` on same `Col1` where the first column cannot be `NULL` as opposed to the second?

To clarify my requirement, consider this sample data with a single row:

```
MaterialNumber(varchar50, not null)    fiModel(int, null, fk)
1234-4321                              1
```

Is it possible to prevent  a second row with the same `MaterialNumber` but a different `fiModel`?

[Here's](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/41a86/2/2) a sql-fiddle, the second `INSERT` should fail since it's a different model with the same number.

In case of link rot:

The (simplified) table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tabSparePartMasterData](
    [MaterialNumber] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [fiModel] [int] NULL)
```

Two rows, the second insert should not be possible:

```
INSERT INTO tabSparePartMasterData(MaterialNumber,fiModel)
VALUES('1234-4321', 1);
INSERT INTO tabSparePartMasterData(MaterialNumber,fiModel)
VALUES('1234-4321', 2);
```

Note that `fiModel` can be `null`, but if it's not null it should not be possible to add another row with the **same or different** `fiModel`. I have already solved the unique index on `MaterialNumber` + `fiModel`(not null) with a computed column. But i'm stuck on how to prevent a different `fiModel`.

Comment: So you would be ok with another entry that has the same `MaterialNumber` as long as it has the same `fiModel`?

Comment: You could *ugh* create a function that receives the `MaterialNumber` and `fiModel` and return a true or false if that combination exists and add that to your check constraint, but....you know, scalar functions. Another alternative is a trigger. (sorry for give you such crappy alternatives)

Comment: You need another table with the allowable `MaterialNumber, fiModel` combinations and a unique constraint on `MaterialNumber`

Comment: @Abe: No, another row with the same material-num and the same non-null fiModel would be a duplicate. I solved this already with a unique Index on a computed column. If fiModel is null the mat-number can repeat. But If it's not null the combination must be unique and also there can only be one model per material.(sorry for typos, I'm on a phone)

Comment: Oh I only read the first bit where you said "prevent a second row with the same MaterialNumber but a different fiModel". The requirement changes further down I see. This just seems like the standard much duplicated question about simulating filtered indexes then. Typically solved with an indexed view with `SELECT MaterialNumber FROM tabSparePartMasterData WHERE fiModel IS NOT NULL` and a unique index on that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a persisted column to the table to support this conditional constraint.  If you dont want to alter this table you can implement the same strategy using a view that projects the `ChkMaterialNumber` column and slapping a unique constraint on that.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tabSparePartMasterData]
(
    [YourPK] int identity(1,1) not null primary key,
    [MaterialNumber] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [fiModel] [int] NULL
);
go

--add a computed column here to enforce the conditional constraint:
alter table [dbo].[tabSparePartMasterData] add [ChkMaterialNumber] as ( case when fiModel is null then cast(YourPK as varchar) else MaterialNumber end)

--now add unique constraint to the computed column:
create unique index ux_SparePartMasterData on [dbo].[tabSparePartMasterData]([ChkMaterialNumber]);
go



-- OK
INSERT INTO tabSparePartMasterData(MaterialNumber,fiModel)
VALUES('1234-4321', 1);

-- FAILS
INSERT INTO tabSparePartMasterData(MaterialNumber,fiModel)
VALUES('1234-4321', 2);

--OK
INSERT INTO tabSparePartMasterData(MaterialNumber,fiModel)
VALUES('1234-4321', null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Editing my answer after understading the problem.

I think the best solution, instead of using trigger or function is to create a new column (I named it as fiModel1) of type UNIQUEIDENTIFIER the should be filled with NEWID() always.

Then create a computed column just like:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tabSparePartMasterData]
    ADD UNIQUECONST as cast([MaterialNumber] as varchar(150)) + case when fiModel is null then    cast(fiModel1 as varchar(150)) else '' end PERSISTED
```

After that you create a constraint for this column like:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tabSparePartMasterData]
ADD CONSTRAINT AK_MaterialNumber UNIQUE (UNIQUECONST);
```

Finally you can will be able to add the first 3 records but not the last one:

```
INSERT INTO tabSparePartMasterData(MaterialNumber,fiModel, fiModel1) VALUES('1234-4321', null, NEWID());
INSERT INTO tabSparePartMasterData(MaterialNumber,fiModel, fiModel1) VALUES('1234-4321', null, NEWID());
INSERT INTO tabSparePartMasterData(MaterialNumber,fiModel, fiModel1) VALUES('1234-4321', 1, NEWID());
INSERT INTO tabSparePartMasterData(MaterialNumber,fiModel, fiModel1) VALUES('1234-4321', 2, NEWID());
```

I think this solve your problem

Comment: How would that cover the case where `fiModel` can be null? You didn't read the OP requirements fully.

Comment: If I understood, the MaterialNumber should be unique. Or can it repeat if the fiModel is null? I didn´t understand that.

Comment: @nizam: thanks for your answer. Yes, the number can repeat if the model is null. If it's not there can only be one model per number. Note that this is a simplified model, actually there are other columns and also a PK-column.